# Windows 2012 Server, Update error 80072EFE

Tags: windows

A new installation of Windows 2012 as a guest inside HyperV 2019.
When trying to update I get the 80072EFE error.

This error indicates a network timeout but internet is working OK. I've ruled out antivirus, firewall, router/gateway filtering, incorrectly configured time/date etc.

When looking at the network traffic generated during unsuccessful update attempt I see a successful TCP handshake between the server and microsoft's update server 40.70.224.149.
However after the handshake the Windows 2012 server sends a Client hello packet and the microsoft's server answers with a RST and ends the connection.

This happens a few times and then I get an error 80072EFE.

I have two more Windows 2012 servers (for a lab) installed from scratch and the same thing happens on them as well.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you run that inside a VM ?

Comment: it is a VM under hyperv, yes.

Comment: What firewalls are you using ? You must allow the VM group through them.

Comment: i've checked the firewalls.

Comment: You must of missed something.

Comment: It is not like I haven't done this a million times before. I have three different gateways in the system (CISCO, Fortigate and Cyberoam). I've tried them all and the result is the same. I've disabled any filtering, AV, packet inspection, IDS etc. Whatever it is, it is not a firewall issue. My guess is, HyperV is acting up in a subtle way. Maybe a restart will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found the solution to this problem.
Basically, I checked the update history of a correctly working Win 2012 server to try to find a clue.
The oldest entry in the log referenced a KB2937636, a Windows update agent.

I manually downloaded and installed that update on my non working Win 2012 servers.
After that, the servers started updating correctly.